# Pdf automation using itext

Tags: pdf, itext

I am using I text API for PDF auto population , i am able to populate almost all PDF fields with database values and i am having issue with three fields. I am not able to set values for the three fields . Can any one suggest me solution
your suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: Without any code probably not I'm sorry. Please edit your question to show [Minimum Complete Verifyable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Without the pdf even less. Please also share a sample pdf with fields you cannot fill.